# Android: "Error while retrieving information from server DFDFERH-01" when trying to download my new published app

Tags: android, google-play

the error indicated in the title is widespread in the network and seems to be due to a cache issue of the Play Store / Play Services, however my problem, when this error occurs, is different.

I published in Play Store a new app about a month ago, it is published correctly according to the console of google play and appears in the lists of the apps in google play store, however, it is not downloadable from desktop or mobile (at the time in the size in the app's card it was written 'null').
I talked to google support but they also can't understand the problem and they suggested (after a month) to publish the app again with another package name.

Yesterday I published this new app but both the new and the old, when I try to download them from mobile, return the following error "**Error while retrieving information from server DFDFERH-01**", from desktop the following error "**There was an unexpected error. Try later.**"

I tried to download also with another device and with another account.

I am sure it is a bug in the play store but no solution found is relevant or working.

Old app (to be removed but the google support has kindly asked me to leave it active to investigate): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps_script_rss_feed.free.michelepisani.it.appsscriptrssfeed

New app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps_script_articoli_e_tutorial.free.michelepisani.it.appsscriptarticolietutorial

Comment: After 4 months of unsatisfactory communications with the support Google Play, I discovered that the problem is a bug of Google Play and was given by the underscorses in the package name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680536/android-application-published-but-not-accessible-or-downloadable-in-the-play-s

Answer (score 0):

Try all step below:

1. Open the "`Google Play`" app and press the home button to return
2. Go to `Settings` → `Applications` → `Manage Applications`
3. Select the "`ALL`" tab, Search for "`Google Play Store`" and press it to open.
4. Press "`Force stop`"
5. Press "`Clear cache`"
6. Press `"Clear Data"`
7. Now Open Play Store and it will work normally.

Comment: Hi LVS, I already tried those steps and I tried them again now, but the problem, as I wrote in the message, seems to be related to the app and it also does if I try to install it from the desktop. Have you tried to install it from the link I provided? In theory it should not allow you to do this by showing you the error indicated in my previous message.