# Android application published, but not accessible (or downloadable) in the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have been talking with the support of the playstore for over 4 months because I have published an application, but despite it being on the playstore it is not possible to install it (or access the related page to download).

The support has suggested me to create a new app and republish it, I did it, but now I have two identical published apps that have the same problem.

In the Google Play Console there are no errors reported in the publication, but of course the download data are 0.

Can you kindly verify the error that returns in order to understand if it is a problem that has already happened to someone, so in order to find the solution?

This is the link to the second app published (identical to the first, but with a different name):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps_script_articoli_e_tutorial.free.michelepisani.it.appsscriptarticolietutorial

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="apps_script_articoli_e_tutorial.free.michelepisani.it.appsscriptarticolietutorial">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="apps_script_articoli_e_tutorial.free.michelepisani.it.appsscriptarticolietutorial.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Although the app is in Italian language I have just made it available to all countries in order to give everyone the opportunity to test the behavior in the play store. Thanks

Comment: I think you should check the countries witch your app is available.

Comment: Says it's not compatible with any of my devices. Do you have anything special going on in your manifest?

Comment: I updated the post with the maniufest but its content is very simple, the application has only one activity with listadapter.
The country available is only Italy because the text inside the app is only in italian.
Play Store say that my device is compatible but I can't download the app from Play Store (just run it if I use the apk directly for build and test).

Comment: EDIT: regarding the availability in the countries, I have just made it available for all countries in order to give everyone the possibility to verify the behavior in the Play Store. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I'm getting the error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later." when I click on "Install" (I've tried with two different accounts as well). Have you told that to the Play support team?

Comment: Exactly Pierre, a problem so strange that I have been trying to solve with the support for 4 months but they do not know why... the app is successfully published but it can't be downloaded... and nobody knows why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Play store and nothing to do with your app. I have made sure that the right people are looking at it. I'm really sorry you've had such a poor experience with Play support, I'll try to investigate to find out why it happened and make sure it doesn't happen to anyone else.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply and your support.
I tried to publish the application twice, with two different package names but without success.
I don't know if it is a good idea that I try to publish the app a third time (perhaps with a package name without underscores or with implementations in gradle updated or other...).
The question is that if any new app that I try to public is not downloadable means that the problem is with my account (or not?). I don't know what I can do...

Comment: I'm 90% sure the problem you currently have will be fixed if you publish an app without underscores in the package name. But it's our bug, not yours.

Comment: I confirm my suspicion supported by Nick's answer. I renamed the app package name for the third time but removing the underscores. This is definitely a bug in Play Store (as Nick also says) because the docs says that "A full Java-language-style package name for the Android app. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters." (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#package) but it is not really like that and the support is not aware of it.